# c - void pointer to struct inside a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void

## EDIT:

the exact error I get is :
error: request for member ‘q’ in something not a structure or union

I corrected the typos I left in the code. It happened while formatting it for SO(camel case..).

### context

Problem to set a void pointer to a struct.

***My initial goal*** : I would like to point to a structure from a void pointer.
pointMe.a will point to pointMe2 so that I can set pointMe2.q with an integer.

***My final goal*** : being able to cast that void pointer to anything, while reusing my pointMe structure. Maybe I could point to a structure and soon after to a char or an integer. Polymorphism I think.

### Failure

Apparently, in the 3) of the code below, q is not part of a struct or a union.
Looking at the pointers addresses, i know I am close but not there yet.

### My funky code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {

    void * a;

}pointMe;

typedef struct {

    int q;

}pointMe2;

int main(void)
{

    pointMe arrow;
    pointMe2 * flesh;

    flesh = malloc(sizeof(pointMe2));
    flesh->q = 4;

    printf("1)\n Value: %d Address: %p\n",flesh->q,flesh );

    arrow.a = flesh;
    printf("2)\n arrow.a's address: %p flesh's address: %p\n",arrow.a,flesh );

    printf("3)\n arrow.a's address: %p Value of q : %d\n",arrow.a, *(arrow.a)->q );

    free(flesh);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arrow.a` is not `arrow.a`'s address, but it's value. Never confuse pointer and pointee, even if both should be pointers. Pointers are objects in their own right.

Comment: i replaced in the 3) %p with %d. My mistake, sorry

Comment: did you try the code i suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors [typos i think] in your code.

1. `pointme arrow;` should be `pointMe arrow;` and so on. [Modified in below code]
2. `value of` should be the value [`int` type], so use `%d` with `printf()`.

Check the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {

    void * a;

}pointMe;

typedef struct {

    int q;

}pointMe2;

int main(void)
{

    pointMe arrow;            //corrected
    pointMe2 * flesh;         //corrected

    flesh = malloc(sizeof(pointMe2));
    flesh->q = 4;

    printf("1)\n Value: %d Address: %p\n",flesh->q,flesh );

    arrow.a = flesh;
    printf("2)\n arrow.a's address: %p flesh's address: %p\n",arrow.a,flesh );

    printf("3)\n arrow.a's address: %p Value of q : %d\n",arrow.a, ((pointMe2 *)(arrow.a))->q );  //corrected

    free(flesh);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to paste in the whole code when changing one line.

Comment: @Jite change is on `more than one line`. Please have a look.

Comment: I updated the code. the mess happened while formating it for you mates. Sorry about that

Comment: Very fine ! Thanks a lot ! But the whole is much more complicated than I thought. I would not have found that one :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh:I want to know more about what happened to me: (pointMe2*)(arrow.a)->q is not sufficient but ((pointMe2*) (arrow.a))->q is because of some precedence, right ?

Comment: @Larry absoutely. precedence.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("3)\n arrow.a's address: %p Value of q : %p\n",arrow.a, *(arrow.a)->q );
```

The `.a` member is a `void` pointer. It is impossible to dereference a `void` pointer because there is no such thing as a `void` type. You have to cast the pointer to the correct type first:

```
printf("3)\n arrow.a's address: %p Value of q : %p\n",
       arrow.a,
       ((pointMe2 *)arrow.a)->q);
```

Note also that the `%p` conversion specifier expects a `void` pointer to be passed. When printing the value of `flesh` you need to cast it to `void *` before passing it to `printf`:

```
printf("1)\n Value: %d Address: %p\n", flesh->q, (void *)flesh );
```

Answer (score -1):

Either use `*(arrow.a).q`, or `(arrow.a)->q`.

Comment: `(arrow.a)->q` (or `arrow.a->q`) is equivalent to `(*(arrow.a)).q` and `(*arrow.a).q` (ignoring that both are invalid without a cast), `.` and `->` have higher precedence than `*`.